# How do I construct a tangent curve path for a conveyor belt?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

I would like to create a curve path for a planar mesh to follow with curve modifier. The curve path could be a curve from the start or converted from mesh to curve. So essentially I want a workflow for stretching a web path between pulleys. Any suggestions? Thanks for reading.